# If the square of an irrational number r is irrational, can it be equal to a + br, where both a and b are rational

Tags: irrational-numbers

I am trying to evaluate such a statement:

$$\forall r \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}: \ ({r^{2}} \notin \mathbb{Q} \implies \forall a \in \mathbb{Q} \ \forall b \in \mathbb{Q}: {r^{2}} \neq a + br)$$

but it seems to exceed my skills. Could you please help?

Comment: Consider the contrapositive. Then it would be easy to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a counterexample:

Set $r = \sqrt{2} +1 \in \mathbb{I}$.

Then $r^{2} = (\sqrt{2} +1)^2=1+2\sqrt{2}+2=1+2(\sqrt{2}+1) = 1+2r.$

Comment: Thank you! So simple! I was convinced that the statement was true so I spent so much effort looking for a proof instead of investigating these kinds of examples.

Comment: You're welcome!